# Why Rows_sent is 0 when that query returns 4 records to mysql client?

Tags: mysql

I would like to find the response or atleast the rows returned for few queries in MySQL. Since slow query log returns the row sent(rows returned to mysql client) is enabled for all queries.
i.e long_query_time = 0

```
select * from tableName where columName='test';
# Time: 2021-07-31T20:36:39.320639+05:30
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []  Id: 29434761
# Query_time: 0.000050  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
```

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: can you show us the slow query log before and after that, i think you confused the values and the queries

Comment: # Time: 2021-07-31T22:10:58.712392+05:30
# User@Host: zcuser-66039742[zcuser-66039742] @  [127.0.0.1]  Id: 29430650
# Query_time: 0.000215  Lock_time: 0.000074 Rows_sent: 4  Rows_examined: 4
SET timestamp=1627749658;
Query

Comment: is this order correct ?

Comment: yes you have the false Rows_sent the order is upside down

Comment: What version of MySQL?  Is the "Query cache" turned on?

Comment: Was there a syntax error in the first one?  Or other error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your snippet of the slow.log is incorrect. Note that an entry *starts* with `Time:` and *ends* with the query:

```
# Time: 2021-07-31T18:46:25.883405Z
# User@Host: Pics[Pics] @ localhost []  Id: 178992
# Query_time: 0.000079  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0 Thread_id: 178992 Errno: 1064 Killed: 0 Bytes_received: 0 Bytes_sent: 205 Read_first: 0 Read_last: 0 Read_key: 0 Read_next: 0 Read_prev: 0 Read_rnd: 0 Read_rnd_next: 0 Sort_merge_passes: 0 Sort_range_count: 0 Sort_rows: 0 Sort_scan_count: 0 Created_tmp_disk_tables: 0 Created_tmp_tables: 0 Start: 2021-07-31T18:46:25.883326Z End: 2021-07-31T18:46:25.883405Z
SET timestamp=1627757185;
select select * from tableName where columName='test';
```

It took 79us for my instance to get a syntax error.

Check for `Errno`.